# Поиск пробела в строке

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

При нахождение пробела в строке нужно завершить программу.

Что именно не так делаю?

```
for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    if (s.find(' '))
    {
        cout << "Найдем пробел";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем здесь цикл?

Comment: [Мануалы](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) не читай @ вопросы задавай. Что возвращает `find()`?

Comment: если уж написали цикл, то проверьте по индексу  `if (s[i] == '  ')` { ... }

Answer (score 4):

1) Здесь не нужен цикл. 2) `find` возвращает не `bool`, а число. `string::npos` если значение не найдено.

```
if (s.find(' ') != string::npos)
{
   cout << "Найден пробел";
}
```

Что бы завершить программу, можно использовать функцию `exit` например.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы используете `s.find()` в цикле - поэтому вы будете получать ответ столько раз, сколько у вас символов в строке.

Функция `find` библиотеки `string` ищет последовательность заданных символов в заданной строке, и возвращает позицию первого вхождения.

Просто вынесите `s.find()` из цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал не через фонд а циклом
for(int I = 0; I < string.size(); i++)
           if(string[i] = ' ')
                   Действие

Answer (score 0):

```
#include 
#include 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
   string query; 
   getline(cin, query); 
   for (int i = 0; i <= query.size(); i++) { 
      if (query[i] == ' ') { 
         cout << i << endl; 
      } 
   } 
   cout << query.size() << endl; 
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Исправьте код, при копировании потерялись include